# How to trigger another ajax request when autocomplete selection is made?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to use autocomplete which call a method on the server to populate the list.

Corresponding JS file calls

```
$(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete(
    {
        source: "requests/search",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //Here I would like to send the parameters.
            var itemid = ui.item.id;
            alert(itemid);
            // How to call another ajax method.
        }
    })
  });
```

Comment: what ajax method have you tried to put in place of alert.please give full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call its `search` method inside `select` event. Try this.

```
$(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete(
    {
        source: "requests/search",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).autocomplete( "search" , ui.item.value );
        }
    })
});
```